# How to check that uuid field is generated when creating a custom user in Django?

Tags: python, django, uuid

I have added an uuid field to the cusom user model. How can I check that every user I'm creating will have the uuid value?

I have tried to print the uuid but it doesn't work.

The field I added is:

`uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)`

Comment: You can either check it in user table of database or get newly created user object and access the uuid field.

Comment: Please show us your models. How did you try to print the uuid field?  You could go to /admin and check if the usermodel has a uuid or like pymaster said and look it up in the db directly.